# There is a sample structure for kotlintest project

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest

I'm currently playing with the Kotlin testing Framework https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest.

I want to know if there is an expected way to structure the project, I mean, like a base project where I can start base on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some KotlinTest sample projects in the main repo here:
https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/tree/master/kotlintest-samples

They use KotlinTest 3.0.x and for gradle users, the build file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.0.3'
}
```

I won't include the Maven example as the pom.xml is verbose because it's XML, but you can find it in the above link.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific way to structure the project just for this testing framework. You should structure it as any other Kotlin project, so your test should go to `your-project/src/test/kotlin/com/jimmy/`

The important thing is just to extend one of available base classes from kotlintest eg. `WordSpec`
You can see how it all (both structure and tests) looks like in kotlintest itself - https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/tree/master/src/test/kotlin/io/kotlintest

Answer (score 0):

You can test your code using spek, Here is the exaple, that might help to implement on your project.

**[Spek Test Example In Kotlin](https://github.com/dharmakshetri/SpekExampleInKotlin)**